# Xamarin ios - how to set view title after delay / async

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I am trying to set the title of a MvxViewController view after a short delay (my real world example is retrieving the title of the page from values returned from an api call).

My View:

```
public class TestView : MvxViewController
{
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        // execute timer after 1 second
        Timer timer = new Timer ((state) => {
            InvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                this.Title = "TITLE";
            });
        }, null, 1000, int.MaxValue);
    }
}
```

The title does not update when you first navigate to the view, however it is updated if you navigate to another controller and then 'back' to this one. Obviously if I set the title without the timer, it works as expected.

I have tried multiple ways to set the view controller's title. None of them set the title from within the timer.

I'm sure I'm missing something basic, like is there something happening in the view's lifecycle (or in mvvmcross) which might be preventing the view from being redrawn after the initial 'viewdidload' is called?

Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT**: I have modified my question to remove the mvvmcross 'viewmodel' to simplify the question, but in my real-world example the view's title is mvx fluent bound to a property on the viewmodel.

Comment: Is `TestTitle += " Updated";` ever called? If you use a timer to update `TestTitle` instead, does it update? Are there any warnings in trace? If you add a `MyTitle` string to your UIViewController and bind that to `TestTitle` then does it get updated via binding? If it does, then is there any way you can update the `Title` from there? What is `Title` in your presentation case - is it the navigation controller title text, the tab bar text, both or something else?

Comment: TestTitle += " Updated" is called, but the view's title (ios UIViewController.Title) does not show on the view until I navigate away and then back. The binding seems fine but I suspect the view's title is updated on the wrong thread. I need to dig into custom restsharp pcl code (not written by me) that is possibly blocking the thread that the title is being updated on? I suspect I'm missing something simple due to my lack of knowledge of threading.